# Move point to another in c#

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I would like to move some point a in two dimensional search space to another point b with some stepsize (_config.StepSize = 0.03).

```
Point a = agent.Location;
Point b = agentToMoveToward.Location;

//---    important        
double diff = (b.X - a.X) + (b.Y - a.Y);
double euclideanNorm = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((b.X - a.X), 2) + Math.Pow((b.Y - a.Y), 2));
double offset = _config.StepSize * ( diff / euclideanNorm );

agent.NextLocation = new Point(a.X + offset, a.Y + offset);
//---
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Well, what test cases did you try?

Comment: Pythagoras shaking his stick at Euclid: "get off my lawn!"

Comment: In a word, no. Your euclideanNorm is basically the hypotenuse, I'm not sure what diff is intended to give you and the offset, even if calculated correctly, is being added to x and y equally meaning a step in a 45 degree angle (if there is a step at all). You need to be looking at the angle of the vector and using that with the hypotenuse to determine the new x and y locations. There are probably some clever ways of calculating that more quickly than Pythagoras but it would work.

Comment: Do you want to move it in a loop straight from one location(a) to another(b)?

Comment: @Hans Passant: Damn Euclid, he's always coming round drunk and sleeping my lawn too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want to move one point **towards** another point and assuming your step size has distance units, then no, your calculation is not correct.

The correct formula is:

- `nextLocation = a + UnitVector(a, b) * stepSize`

In C#, using just a simple `Point` class and the `Math` library, this looks like:

```
public Point MovePointTowards(Point a, Point b, double distance)
{
    var vector = new Point(b.X - a.X, b.Y - a.Y);
    var length = Math.Sqrt(vector.X * vector.X + vector.Y * vector.Y);
    var unitVector = new Point(vector.X / length, vector.Y / length);
    return new Point(a.X + unitVector.X * distance, a.Y + unitVector.Y * distance);
}
```

**Edit:** Updated code as per TrevorSeniors suggestion in comments

Comment: This doesn't compile as is. `length` is a double *and* will always be bigger than the X/Y components of the vector that went into making it. Meaning that `new Point()` will always be {0,0}.

Comment: @Brad: The question didn't make clear which `Point` class was being used.  You are right that the code above assumes one that supports doubles like [`System.Windows.Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.point.aspx) or a custom class.  When using `System.Drawing.Point` or other integer-based point class the code needs to be adapted accordingly.

Comment: ahhh interesting! I didn't know about the System.Windows.Point class. Nice

Comment: +1 this helped me out a lot. Are your `X` and `Y` wrong in the return statement? e.g. it should be `a.Y + unitVector.Y` instead of `a.X`? That got it working for me, though my situation may be different.