# Move a point towards another point, by a certain distance

Tags: c#, .net

I'm sorry if I couldn't explain the title very well.

I've done research, and could not find any answers on this topic.

```
Point Start;
Point End;
float Distance;
```

This is what I need help with, I need to move point **Start** towards point **End**, only **Distance** long.

So lets say **Start** is at **(0, 0)**, and **End** is at **(11, 17)**, and **Distance** is **2.5**.

The slope would be **17/11** aka **17 over 11**. But what is the distance between the two  points? Lets say the distance between the two points is 20f. I want to move point **Start** towards point **End**, by **Distance**, which is **2.5f**.

So at the end, the distance between point **Start** and point **End** would be **17.5**(20-2.5).

But, as I mentioned before, I couldn't find any thing on the internet or on these forums about this. *How do I get the distance between two points(not the slope)? And how do I move a point along the distance, by a certain distance?*

Hope I can explain myself. Thanks

Comment: Belongs http://math.stackexchange.com/ imo

Comment: These should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702782/move-point-to-another-in-c-sharp http://cboard.cprogramming.com/game-programming/123811-move-point.html

Comment: I'll check them out and get back to you.

Comment: Couldn't edit previous comment, but thanks a lot! I finally got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for responding to an old question, but the selected answer is not fully correct.

```
yDiff = Math.Abs(Start.Y - End.Y);
xDiff = Math.Abs(Start.X - End.X);
distance = Math.Sqrt(yDiff * yDiff + xDiff * xDiff)
```

Notice how there's a multiplication * operator between the two xDiffs, instead of a + sign.

If you put a + sign instead of * sign, then the X distance will appear to be shorter than it actually is. Took me a while to find this bug, I've been searching the wrong places for a while now... -.-

Comment: This shows how to find the distance though, not how to move the point towards the other one

Comment: this is not answering the question

Answer (score 1):

use the right angle triangle relationship:

```
c*c = a*a + b*b
```

where c is the longest side (hypotenuse)
So:

```
yDiff = Math.Abs(Start.Y - End.Y);
xDiff = Math.Abs(Start.X - End.X);
distance = Math.Sqrt(yDiff *yDiff + xDiff*xDiff)
```

Comment: This is it. Same as what I had. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `xDiff * xDiff` not  `xDiff + xDiff`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a point, slope, distance :

You can use the following formula to get the coordinate:

```
Y = m(d/(1+m^2)^(1/2) + x) - mx + y, x=0,y=0, d= 2.5, m=17/11
```

and then you can get X by solving the following equation.

```
Y=17/11(X)
```