# Find existence of location(lat,lon) between two location(lat,lon)

Tags: c#

I have two points(Locations) with their latitude and longitude, "A" and "B". Now I want to find out that is third point(Location) "C" exist or not between A and B. I do have latitude and longitude of C.

How can I check existence of point C in radios of 10 km of A and B please check below explanation.

"Between" A and B explanation:

```
________10KM_______
|                  |
|         C        |
|10KM          10KM|
|                  |
A -------10KM----- B
|                  | 
|10KM          10KM|
|                  |  
|______10KM________|
```

I already have visited below questions but I am unable to think the way.

1. [find location between two other locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334260/find-location-between-two-other-locations)
2. [Finding coordinates of a point between two points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886092/finding-coordinates-of-a-point-between-two-points)

Comment: Your question is not complete.  "Between" can mean *so many* different things when you are talking about geography.  Please edit your question to include a definition of "between".

Comment: Thanks @SamAxe to point out the specification.

Comment: You need to find the distance between A and C; and B and C, and compare those distances to your threshold (10km).  Since lat/long are in degrees, and the ratio of a degree to a km changes based on longitude.. you can either use a geospatial library to calculate this (usually expensive and difficult) or you can approximate it with the [haversine](https://www.google.com?q=haversine) function.

Comment: Bingo.
Thanks @SamAxe to give me the idea. It solves my query.

Comment: You can use `GeoCoordinate`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808858(v=vs.110).aspx which has a method `GetDistanceTo` to find the distance between two GeoCoordinate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining "between A and B" as "within 10 km of A and within 10 km of B", then you can use the haversine calculation to check both distances. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto(v=vs.110).aspx

Now, the way you have defined "between" has problems, in my opinion.  Consider the shape made by intersecting a 10 km circle centered on A and another centered on B, like a Ven diagram.  If A and B are close (say, 2 km apart), there are plenty of points in the intersecting region that don't look "between".

Instead, instead of a fixed 10 km, I would choose the radius of your circle dynamically, based on the actual haversine distance between A and B.  For example, if R = m * d (A, B).

For m = 1 the center of one circle meets the edge of the other, which I think corresponds better with a notion of "betweenness".  You can experiment with drawing pictures for other m's between 1 and 2.